# QuickBooks CustomerAdd request failing due to malformed xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, loopbackjs, quickbooks, qbwc

Question: Am i sending the proper XML request? AM i missing any required information? I'm using the following documentation from QuickBooks to compare XMLOps: https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Im creating a new [LoopbackJS Connector for QuickBooks](https://github.com/TeknoloGenie/loopback-connector-quickbooks) and ive ran into a snag when creating new records, i can query records perfectly fine.

I've looked at several other qbXML requests when it comes to Adding new records, specifically the CustomerAdd request and what im sending off to the Web Connector seems to be exactly what others are using (and its working for them). My guess is somethings wrong within the loopback-connect-quickbooks itself and not the request im sending but im gonna give it a go and post it anyways. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq requestID="2">
      <CustomerAdd>
        <FirstName>Anne</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>B</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Williams</LastName>
        <Name>Anne B Williams</Name>
        <ShipToAddress>
          <Name>Anne B Williams</Name>
        </ShipToAddress>
      </CustomerAdd>
    </CustomerAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the OSR again, and remember -- **the order of the tags *IS* important**.

The OSR shows the tags in this order:

```
<Name >STRTYPE</Name> <!-- required -->
...
<FirstName >STRTYPE</FirstName> <!-- optional -->
<MiddleName >STRTYPE</MiddleName> <!-- optional -->
<LastName >STRTYPE</LastName> <!-- optional -->
```

And you have them in this order:

```
    <FirstName>Anne</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>B</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Williams</LastName>
    <Name>Anne B Williams</Name>
```

You must follow the order of the tags shown in the OSR. Fix the order of the tags and your request should go through fine.

Side note - there's an `XML Validator` tool included with the `QuickBooks SDK` that will tell you EXACTLY what your error is in cases like this.

Comment: no way? It requires it to be in order, okay im going to try this now... I'll get back to you within 5minutes

Comment: Yeah, it's super weird -- it requires it to be in a specific order.

Comment: Thank you, it took me awhile to get the JavaScript logic down to parse it from an js object to xml but i finally got it to render it out in the order that it needed to be in. I'll be sure to give you credits on GitHub since its an open sourced project.

Comment: Haha, i didn't notice who you were until just now. I used alot of the foundation to your PHP project to develop this. So credits will definitely go out to the consolibyte/quickbooks-php project if thats okay with you.

Comment: Awesome! So glad I could help contribute!  Link to project?

Comment: Yeah sure, here it is. I'll also post it in the question. https://github.com/TeknoloGenie/loopback-connector-quickbooks